# Django Queryset instead of for loops and if statements in views.py

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've got the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("created on"))
    liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='liked_post')
    disliked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='disliked_post')

   `def get_tag_weight(self):
        tag_set = Tag.objects.filter(post=self)
        tag_weight = 0
        for tag in tag_set:
           tag_weight += tag.weight
        return tag_weight`

class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent_post')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='post')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

and in accounts

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(
    default=uuid.uuid4,
    editable=False,
    primary_key=True
)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
liked_posts = models.ManyToManyField('post.Post',  blank=True, related_name='user_liked')
disliked_posts = models.ManyToManyField('post.Post',  blank=True, related_name='user_disliked')
liked_tags = models.ManyToManyField('post.Tag' , blank=True, related_name='user_liked')
disliked_tags = models.ManyToManyField('post.Tag', blank=True, related_name='user_disliked')
```

Here is my get_queryset method in views.py

```
class PostListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 
serializer_class = GetUserIDSerializer
serializer_class_post = PostSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
queryset = ''
context_object_name = "post_list"

def get_queryset_Post(self, user):
    liked_tags = user.liked_tags.all()
    disliked_tags = user.disliked_tags.all()
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    sorted_posts = []
    liked_posts = []
    disliked_posts = []
    normal_posts = []
    for post in posts:
        is_break = False
        is_added = False
        post_tags = Tag.objects.filter(post=post)
        for tag in post_tags:
            if is_break:
                break
            for liked_tag in liked_tags:
                if tag.name == liked_tag.name:
                    liked_posts.append(post)
                    is_break = True
                    is_added = True
                    break
            else:
                for disliked_tag in disliked_tags:
                    if tag.name == disliked_tag.name:
                        disliked_posts.append(post)
                        is_added = True
                        is_break = True
                        break
        if is_added == False:
            normal_posts.append(post)
            continue
    for i in range(len(liked_posts)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(liked_posts)):
            if liked_posts[i].get_tag_weight() < liked_posts[j].get_tag_weight():
                liked_posts[i], liked_posts[j] = liked_posts[j], liked_posts[i]
    for i in range(len(disliked_posts)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(disliked_posts)):
            if disliked_posts[i].get_tag_weight() > disliked_posts[j].get_tag_weight():
                disliked_posts[i], disliked_posts[j] = disliked_posts[j], disliked_posts[i]
    sorted_posts = liked_posts  + normal_posts + disliked_posts
    return sorted_posts
```

I want to remove loops(all for loop and if statements) from views and want queryset do the calculations.I want to write query that will filter posts which have tags similar to liked tags by user. I know this is pretty long . See if anyone can help.Thank you

Comment: it is really hard to follow the code, can you please share what you want to do here?

Comment: I want to shift all calculation part from views.py to  Queryset.

Comment: no, the logic behind those for loops and if-elses

Comment: I have given full code of view .I want to remove all for and if statements in get_queryset method  and write query instead

Comment: Logic is to get set of posts based on posts users previously liked or disliked and hence tags associated with posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your approach of a `ForeignKey` from Tag to Post is problematic. From what I understand Posts can have similar tags. A `ManyToManyField` would better suit this situation:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    # Other fields
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='tags')
    # Other fields
```

Now moving on to the views, we'll filter using the tags and order by max weight:

```
from django.db.models import Max

    liked_posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=user.liked_tags.all()).annotate(max_weight=Max('tags__weight')).order_by('-max_weight')
    normal_posts = Post.objects.exclude(tags__in=user.liked_tags.all()).exclude(tags__in=user.disliked_tags.all()).annotate(max_weight=Max('tags__weight')) # Might just need to annotate for union to work.
    disliked_posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=user.disliked_tags.all()).annotate(max_weight=Max('tags__weight')).order_by('max_weight')
    sorted_posts = liked_posts | normal_posts | disliked_posts
```